# Bash script wait if already running, then continue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script that is called by a program once a process is complete. I need a way for that bash script to wait if another instance of itself is running to exit before continuing. I can't just use lock files and exit because the script will not be called again on any kind of regular schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't just use lock files and exit because the script will not be called again on any kind of regular schedule.

Within the script, before creating the lock file, you can loop through checking if the lock file exists, if it does, continue looping (through a `sleep` command or something) and when it goes away, create it.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ -e /var/tmp/bash_script.lock ];
do
    sleep 5
done

touch /var/tmp/bash_script.lock

echo "do something"

rm /var/tmp/bash_script.lock
```

Comment: umm.. bad race condition in doing it that way.  imagine several processes trying to run.. First has the lock.  Second and Third both see when First has ended and both touch the file, one removes the file before the other was finished and a Fourth could incorrectly get in.

Answer (score 1):

use `ps -df` command which lists all the PIDs and PPIDs running on your system. Now you can include a code that will parse `ps -df` output and check for running instances of `bash script` iy answer is yes `exit 1` the present script