# How to Synchronize the bash shell

Tags: shell, synchronize

I'm trying to make some code that start docker container automately.
So i already make shell script to run the container.
and now I'm making the script run the all script i made.

like this

```
IP=$1
WEBPORT=$2
STREAMPORT=$3
NAME=$4
ID=$5
PASSWARD=$6
RTSP=$7

#create Container
bash ./docker_script/create_container.sh $IP $WEBPORT $STREAMPORT $NAME

#start Container
bash ./docker_script/start_container.sh $IP $NAME

#setting for using kerberos

#1 Setup user and PASSWARD
bash ./kerberos_script/setup_account_script.sh $IP $WEBPORT $ID $PASSWARD
```

But for making container and run some time is take. 
So i want to make to run each script to be run after the script befored was done.

Is there anyway to run the code synchronize?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854295/bash-script-wait-if-already-running-then-continue

Comment: I can't understand what you touch on.

while [ -e /var/tmp/bash_script.lock ];

what is mean this code?

Comment: Oh I undertand now .
that's means if i want to block some code check that process by using lock file? is right?

Comment: But i can't sure is it possible to unblock? 
I mean i think i can't unlock

Comment: While loop keep sleeping when there is a lock file, so when there is no lock file, new lock file is created, then you can run your script and be sure that only one instance is running. At the end of your script run `rm /var/tmp/bash_script.lock` so you unblock another instance.